# Can't get AJAX script to work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a table which has a list of transactions and am trying to do update the table contents at set intervals. I am running this page on a linux red hat server. It is just the AJAX that is not working right now.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function updateTrans() {
                var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.HTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("transactions").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }

                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "update_trans.txt", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

            window.setInterval(updateTrans(), 4000);
        </script>
        <link href="trans_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
         <h1 id="heading"> Chomp The Bit </h1>

        <div id="transactions">
            <table id="trans_tbl" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Latest Transactions</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
                    <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
                    <td>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
                    <td>dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
                    <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</td>
                    <td>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</td>
                    <td>gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</td>
                    <td>hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</td>
                    <td>iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</td>
                    <td>jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can you tell there's anything wrong? Are you getting any error?

Comment: it wont change any of the content.. when i simplify the ajax and take some stuff out, the javascript will work and get the div section, but it doesnt replace it with the content of the text file

Comment: i could... i dont know any jquery though.. also, these transactions wont be coming from a database.. it will be from the bitcoin network

Comment: i do know some php and mysql if that would work though

Comment: i really dont know ajax.. i have been learning it just for this project... at this point, i am just trying to get it to insert the content of the text file into the div

Comment: First off, use a client-side framework like jQuery, instead of handling creation if the XmlHttpRequest object. Frameworks like JQuery do this for you out of the box and handle all the cross-browser nuances for you. Secondly, don't use setInterval, use setTimeout where the callback function is your polling function

Comment: the only error i can see says "failed to load resource"

Comment: i have tried the setTimeOut, it wouldnt do anything either

Comment: what is update_trans.txt?

Comment: i was just looking at some jquery... when i "install" it, should i do it in the same directory as my site? or if not, where should i install the library?

Comment: This code should work fine, make sure `update_trans.txt` is not empty.

Comment: it is just a table... basically, <table> <tr><td>kdljfakdjf</td></tr> <tr><td>adlkfja;da;dlksfj</td> </table>

Comment: once you have downloaded the jquery file just include it in your js folder or wherever in the project and just include it like any other javascript

Comment: where should i download the jquery file, or library?? i am on a linux server.. should i put in the directory of my pages?

Comment: I think you need to do a bit of reading first. Go to http://docs.jquery.com and read up on selectors, events and the ever so famous $(document).ready. Also, provide code samples that people can help you with. There are sites like http://jsfiddle.net that allow you to test markup, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: include this in your head tag:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: right on, thank you... and can jquery just update sections of a page, rather than refreshing the whole page itself?

Comment: go and take a look at jquery .ajax()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have, `update_trans.txt` file in the same directory, and it is not empty.

```
        <head>
            <script>
                function updateTrans() {
                    var xmlhttp;

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.HTTP");
                    }

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("transactions").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }

                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "update_trans.txt", true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }

                window.setInterval(updateTrans(), 4000);
            </script>
            <link href="trans_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>

        <body>
             <h1 id="heading"> Chomp The Bit </h1>

            <div id="transactions">

             </div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will fix the issue, but you should do `window.setInterval(updateTrans, 4000)` rather than `window.setInterval(updateTrans(), 4000)`. That is, you should pass a reference to the function as the first argument to `setInterval`, rather than the return value of *calling* the function, which is what you're doing in your current code. In your current code, `updateTrans` will get called one time -- when you call it yourself -- but won't get called every 4000ms, as you seem to intend.

I'd also recommend that you use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` -- I wrote [a post about this](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2013/02/04/refactoring-setInterval-polling/).